# Can I get a list of Pages that have installed my Tab app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tabs

I've seen a similar question asked a few times, but usually it is from people trying to find out which Page is currently accessing their Tab app.  (Which you can do by inspecting the signed_request.)

I'm trying to build a UI that will show the user all the Pages that he/she is an Admin of, and then display which of those Pages have my Tab app already installed.  I'd like to make a FB graph API call to either a) get the list of Pages that have my Tab app installed or b) get a yes/no answer for whether a particular Page has it installed.  Is this possible?

As a fallback, I will make a table in my database to track Page IDs whenever a Page views my Tab (using the aforementioned signed_request) but this won't be as good, because it won't know when someone has uninstalled the Tab from a Page.

Comment: AFAIK it's missing from the API, I've looked for that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, 'no', without keeping track on your side via the `signed_request` but if you're already obtaining `manage_pages` access from the user it's pretty trivial to check if a particular app (i.e, yours) is installed on the page

See the [page documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) for details, relevant part:

```
You can test if a specific app is installed on a page profile tab by issuing an
HTTP GET to PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID. If the app is installed, this will return the 
following fields:
```

(you'll need the page access token from the user's `/accounts` connection for that call

Comment: I already require `manage_pages` in order to show the list of pages that the user admins (btw this seems overkill, just to show the list, but that's another subject).  So this technique works for me.  Not as convenient as getting a list of Pages with my Tab installed, but good enough.

Answer (score 4):

To be complete (for future readers): this does not require `manage_pages`. You can also use the FB app's token. Also see: [Check if page tab app is still installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198530/check-if-page-tab-app-is-still-installed)