# Retrieve list of facebook pages with a specific application installed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get a list of Pages that have installed my Tab app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738150/can-i-get-a-list-of-pages-that-have-installed-my-tab-app)

I'm trying to get some table where i can find the information that relates the application with the pages where the application page tab appears, i'm using Facebook API, but i don't know where to get that tables or info that i have so much need of , I've surfed this pages with no result so far:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

I intent to use a query using fql to retrieve that, or anything else you think will work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to do this with FQL, however the Pages API (via Graph API) has a solution for you here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

You can pass in /PAGE_ID/tabs and it will return an array of the page's tabs including each app ID.