# Facebook App - pages that my app is installed in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I use the Graph API Explorer or FQL to determine which pages have my application installed ?

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but can Pages install apps? I thought only users could do that.

Comment: Possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738150/can-i-get-a-list-of-pages-that-have-installed-my-tab-app

Comment: Yes users can install a facebook tab application in pages that they own. I want those page ids or links or anything that points on those pages.

Comment: @DeepakLakshmanan I know how to check if my application is installed on a known page. But I don t know how to check the same for pages that I haven t authorize to do so.